# Example of subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ which is not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

> I was looking for a proper subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ which is not finitely generated under the addition operation.

We know every finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ is cyclic. For a proper subgroup I am just thinking about the subgroup $H$ generated by $\{\frac{1}{p} : p \text{ prime }\}$ may work. It seems $1/4$ is not in $H.$ Is this a  correct example? Thanks

Comment: @CAA: Your example is correct.  It consists of fractions whose reduced form has a square free denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $\mathbb Z[\frac12]$, that is, the set of binary fractions.

More generally, $\mathbb Z[\frac1p]$, that is, the set of fractions whose denominators are powers of the prime $p$.

Comment: Thank you lhf . Is $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}] = \{a + b/2 : a, b \in \mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: No, it's the set of all fractions whose denominators are a power of $2$. Your $\{a + b/2 : a, b \in \mathbb Z\}$ is finitely generated (by $1$ and $1/2$, and so by $1/2$ alone).

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you so much @lhf.

Comment: That would be then $\Bbb Z [ \frac 1 2]=\{\frac 1 {2^k}: k \in \Bbb Z\}$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Actually, it would be $\{\frac{j}{2^k}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. These are commonly known as the _dyadic rationals_ and you can find more information on them searching under that name.