# Classification of subgroups of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ that are not finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, rational-numbers

Proper subgroups of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ that are not finitely generated exist, e.g., [Example of subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ which is not finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346600/example-of-subgroup-of-mathbb-q-which-is-not-finitely-generated).

Is there a classification of subgroups of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ that are not finitely generated?

Comment: See the more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/how-to-find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbq

Answer (score 8):

Let $P$ be the set of all prime numbers and let $f: P\to\mathbb{N}\cup\infty$ be an arbitrary function.
Let
$$
N_f=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid n=\prod_{p\in P} p^{k_p}, k_p\leq f(p)\}.
$$
Let $\mathbb{Q}_f=\{a/b\mid a\in\mathbb{Z},b\in N_f\}$.

> **Theorem.** For any function $f$ the set $\mathbb{Q}_f$ is a subgroup.
>
> If $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$, then there exists a function $f$
> and an non-negative integer $m$ that $H=m\mathbb{Q}_f$.
>
> The subgroup $m\mathbb{Q}_f$ is finitely generated (and hence cyclic)
> if and only if $f(p)<\infty$ for every prime $p$ and $f(p)>0$ only for
> a finite number of prime.

Examples.

1. If $f(2)=\infty$, $f(p)=0$ for all $p\in P$, $p\neq2$, then we obtain a subgroup $\mathbb{Q}_2=\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$
   (see [Example of subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is not finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346600)).
2. If $f(p)=\infty$ for each $p\in P$, then $\mathbb{Q}_f=\mathbb{Q}$.
3. If $f(p)=1$ for each $p\in P$, then $\mathbb{Q}_f=\operatorname{gr}(1/p\mid p\in P)$.
4. If $f(2)=a>0$ and $f(p)=0$ for each $p\neq2$, then $\mathbb{Q}_f=\operatorname{gr}(1/2^a)$ is a cyclic group.

You can read about it in [How to find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/how-to-find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbq) and
in the article
Ross A. Beaumont and H. S. Zuckerman, [A characterization of the subgroups of the additive rationals](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103052189), Pacific J. Math. Volume 1, Number 2 (1951), 169-177.

**Adding.**
In this connection it seems useful to read the chapter 'Torsion-Free Groups' of Laszlo Fuchs' book Abelian Groups.  Any edition (and there are many) of this book has such a chapter.

Comment: FYI I glanced through my copy of [**Abelian Groups**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/abelian-groups/oclc/998799) by Fuchs (1960), looking at *Subject Index* listings for "rational group" (pp. 25, 149, 171, 211, 270), and found a possible lead in a in a 1937 **Duke Mathematical Journal** paper -- [*Abelian groups without elements of finite order*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-3/issue-1/Abelian-groups-without-elements-of-finite-order/10.1215/S0012-7094-37-00308-9.short) by Baer -- but only the first page **(continued)**

Comment: is viewable and it wasn't clear to me that Baer's paper was worth mentioning. However, if I had looked through Fuchs' *Bibliography* (I didn't have the time or interest), then I would have seen the Beaumont/Zuckerman paper near the bottom of the first page of the *Bibliography*, and its title would definitely led me to investigate further.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for bringing this to my attention. I made a small addition to my reply.